# Custom checkbox state not updating on bootstrap collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have searched for a while and tried a few different things - but for the life of me can't seem to get this working.

In the codepen below is an example of custom checkbox with a div toggled to show/hide when the checkbox is checked, and also a normal checkbox where the collapse functionality and checkbox work as intended

Can't for the life of me understand why the custom checkbox doesn't change states when checked - if i remove the data-toggle the custom checkbox works, but as soon as the data-toggle is introduced it fails.

```
codepen.io/anon/pen/JzYOpZ
```

In case it's not clear - i would like the checkbox state to toggle between checked / not checked when clicked & to show the collapsible div.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `fill` property of the svg using different classes
Here is the updated Pen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYjppK

The css i changed was following

```
.cbx span:first-child svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 2px;
    stroke: #FFFFFF;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-dasharray: 16px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.cbx span:first-child svg {
  fill: blue;
}

.cbx.collapsed span:first-child svg {
  fill: none;
}
```

And while the checkbox is loaded initially i added the collapsed class to the checkbox as follows

```
<label class="cbx collapsed" for="test" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't look like it fixes the root issue that checkbox doesn't change states, if you take the display:none; off the input box you'll see it doesn't change.

Comment: I thought the issue was just with the UI with the custom checkbox

Comment: No problem! Have updated the question to make it more clear, thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Unless you are actively avoiding JavaScript, a simple solution would be to implement a function to change the state:

HTML Change:

```
<div class="checkbox" onclick="checkIt()">
```

JavaScript Function:

```
function checkIt()
{
  if (document.getElementById("test").checked == false)
    {
      document.getElementById("test").checked = true;
    }
  else
    {
      document.getElementById("test").checked = false;
    } 
}
```

Edit:
Don't forget to link the script file should you choose this answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Javascript solutions are fine, but if the content is dynamically generated and i don't know the ID until the page is rendered - how would i amend the above function to get this ID only? Thanks for the answer by the way!

Comment: You could pass the ID as an argument of the function, i.e. checkIt(ID) and then replace "test" with ID in the script. That way when you call the function you can pass the generated ID.

Comment: @lamps92 Let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: Not sure it will work, since im clicking the label (input with the ID is set to display:none; to make custom checkbox styling work) - so no ID would get passed on the click event, unless im misunderstanding? Which i could be as im a JS novice :D

Comment: Hey Jack! I finally worked it out, answer is below but thanks for your help

Comment: Good to hear, No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer to this was actually infuriatingly simple

Instead of using the href attribute to target the div you want to collapse, you need to make sure you're using "data-target"

I have updated the codepen in the question to reflect this.